# Fill under MATLAB binary image of line

Tags: matlab

I have a binary image of a line that reaches both sides of the image and would like to fill the section under it. I can't get imfill(); to do anything because it is only a line and not a closed shape. I think possibly adding a border along the bottom half of the image would do that, but I've looked through most of the documentation and haven't found anything about being able to specify one. Is there any way I could fill the gap underneath the line in my image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`cummax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cummax.html) (cumulative max) down the columns to do this. This will result in an image with is `0` until it hits a `1` in each column and thereafter it will yield all `1`'s. This will essentially "fill" the image in below the line.

```
BW = [0 0 1;
      0 1 0;
      1 0 0];

BW = cummax(BW, 1);

%     0     0     1
%     0     1     1
%     1     1     1
```

If you're using a version of MATLAB that's older than R2014b, you could do something similar with `cumsum`

```
BW = cumsum(BW, 1) > 0;
```

Comment: Is there any way to actually draw the boundary out?

Comment: I meant, is there a way to draw a line around the border of the image.

Comment: @MiaGarbaccio I'm confused what you want. That has nothing to do with your original question. Are you saying that you also want the entire boundary of the image to be `1`?

Comment: @MiaGarbaccio Did you even try my answer? You don't need `imfill`

Comment: I'm not able to use cummax to fill a shape without boundaries, and I've tried bwboundaries before and was only able to get it to work on objects, the sides of the image don't contain anything.

Comment: @MiaGarbaccio I think you should post your image and the code you're trying.